# read image but show strange colour

Tags: image, matlab

I have read a image like that

```
a = imread('test.jpg');
image(a)
```

what the test.jpg is:

[image: Original image]

but after the image function

the result is:

[image: Obtained image]

and I don't know why it show that?

Because I want to crop some part, so I have to see the image shown.

How to fix it by showing the human face by image?

Comment: Please show the code that you use to process and display image.

Comment: try `imagesc` instead and show the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `image` command to display an image. From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html): "image creates an image graphics object by interpreting each element in a matrix as an index into the figure's colormap or directly as RGB values". Since you are providing a 2-D matrix, each element is interpreted as the index to the figures colormap. You can see the figure's colormap by using

```
 c_map=colormap;
```

Also, the axis is set to square, therefore you see a circle instead of an ellipse. Use `imshow(a,[])`  to display the grayscale image as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You image data might be in a color map instead. try `[a,cmap] = imread(...)`. If cmap is not empty, `a` is indices into `cmap`, and `cmap` contains the actual colors.
Use `img = cat(3,cmap(a,1),cmap(a,2),cmap(a,3))` to get your image, and show it with `image(img)`.

Note that using `imagesc` might be misleading in this case as it will still show something that looks like your image when simply doing `imagesc(a)`. This as different pixels colors are associated with different index-values in `a`.